# How to center buttons

Tags: html, css

Just started learning CSS. I managed to align buttons to the left. But I want to have them in the center. When I am changing float:left to float:center, buttons appear in the center, but size of the buttons changes depending on the text inside, I want them all to be the same size as in the first picture and without margins. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsaAO.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8M2o.png

```css
.button{
    width: 80px;
    padding: 12px;
    float: center;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    background: lightblue;  
 }
```

```html
  <div id="List">
           
                    <a class="button">HTML</a>
                    <a class="button">CSS</a>
                    <a class="button">JavaScript</a>
                    <a class="button">C#</a>
                    <a class="button" href="Unity.html">Unity</a>
                
         </div>
```

Comment: Can you add the `html` too ?

Comment: Please add HTML aswell

Comment: If I got what you mean, just add `margin: 0 auto` to button's wrapper element.

Comment: There is no `float: center`

Comment: you can also target the `#List` container and do `text-align: center;`

Answer (score 6):

`float: center` is not a thing:

[image]

I'd recommend getting into learning flexbox, as your problem can be solved using it simply:

```css
#List {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  width: 80px;
  padding: 12px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="List">

  <a class="button">HTML</a>
  <a class="button">CSS</a>
  <a class="button">JavaScript</a>
  <a class="button">C#</a>
  <a class="button" href="Unity.html">Unity</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `float` for anything besides aligning images within text.

The proper solution would be to use `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;`, like so: (also, don't forget to set `flex: 0;` on the button)

```css
.list {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.button {
    width: 80px;
    padding: 12px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    background: lightblue;
    flex: 0; 
}
```

```html
<div id="List" class="list">
  <a class="button">HTML</a>
  <a class="button">CSS</a>
  <a class="button">JavaScript</a>
  <a class="button">C#</a>
  <a class="button" href="Unity.html">Unity</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using float on your buttons Use Margin Auto on your parent container.
Also avoid using floats as much as you can, Now that Modern features like Flexbox and Grid are available.

```
#list{
margin : 0 auto;
}
```